# conversion from character to numeric when the length is 25

Tags: formatting, sas

i have a variable which is in character format. for example the variable has a value : 112002500501002106302001 which is of length 25. i want to convert it into numeric variable.

i'm using the standard code:

```
data trial1 ;
    set trial;
    code1 = input(CODE,25);
    run;
```

the value is now in the form 1.120025E23

```
data trial1 ;
set trial;
code1 = input(CODE,25);
format code1 best25.;
run;
```

but the result that i'm getting is not accurate.

i'm using sas 9.3

Answer (score 2):

All numbers are doubles in SAS.  From Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) "Between 2^52=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2^53=9,007,199,254,740,992 the representable numbers are exactly the integers."

So lets run a loop to convert the string to a number:

```
data test;
format x $25. y z best32.;
x = '112002500501002106302001';
a = '9,007,199,254,740,992';
y = input(x,best32.);
put x=;
put y=;

z = 0;
do i=1 to 24;
    z = sum(z,10**(i-1)*input(substr(x,length(x)-i+1,1),best.));
    put i z= comma32.;
end;
run;
```

Outputs:

```
x=112002500501002106302001
y=112002500501002105389056
1 z=1
2 z=1
3 z=1
4 z=2,001
5 z=2,001
6 z=302,001
7 z=6,302,001
8 z=6,302,001
9 z=106,302,001
10 z=2,106,302,001
11 z=2,106,302,001
12 z=2,106,302,001
13 z=1,002,106,302,001
14 z=1,002,106,302,001
15 z=501,002,106,302,001
16 z=501,002,106,302,001
17 z=501,002,106,302,001
18 z=500,501,002,106,302,016
19 z=2,500,501,002,106,301,952
20 z=2,500,501,002,106,301,952
21 z=2,500,501,002,106,301,952
22 z=2,002,500,501,002,106,175,488
23 z=12,002,500,501,002,105,389,056
24 z=112,002,500,501,002,088,611,840
```

You will notice between the 17 and 18 iteration, the number breaks down.  This is over the threshold which a double precision can no longer represent an exact integer (9,007,199,254,740,992).

Answer (score 0):

SAS uses 8 bytes to store numeric variables.  There is a limit on the size of an integer that can be represented accurately.  See numeric precision, e.g.

[TS654: Numeric Precision 101](https://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts654.pdf)

If this is a character code, probably best to just leave it as a character variable.

Comment: While this is a correct answer, too much of the information is stored behind the link.  A better answer would include the relevant information (such as the maximum stored number) in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Interesting to see the different cultures on different sites (I'm most familiar with SAS-L)  Will keep this in mind. Guess short responses with links like this are better as comments here.

Comment: Short responses with links should just not be posted until you have time to expound on them. Comments are for clarifying the question.